# Пароль пользователя и sql-инъекция

Tags: взлом, php

Вот вопрос такой.

Все передаваемые на сервер данные из формы можно проверить, используя множество способов, включая регулярные выражения и подготовленные запросы stmt и PDO. А как быть с паролем? Ведь пользователю **разрешено** использовать абсолютно любые символы в написании пароля, в том числе и микрострочку sql-инъекции! Конечно, пароль можно сразу же кодировать в md5, но как быть, если, например, пароль должен храниться в БД mysql не в закодированном виде, а в настоящем (например, для восстановления забытого)?

Comment: Для востановления генерируется новый пароль. ПО соображениям безопасности(а вдруг уведут таблицу с паролями) никогда не храните пароли в открытом виде.

Comment: @terantul, никогда не храню! Боже упаси! Просто задумался - на серьезных порталах есть такая фишка - восстановление первоначального пароля

Comment: А почему именно про пароль такой вопрос возник? В других данных тоже может быть что угодно...

Comment: @klopp, ну, вы меня поняли))) сегодня пароль, завтра - что-то серьезней. Задумался просто, если пароль хранить как он есть, то как делать select запросы по логину и паролю, который как раз может содержать иньекцию. В общем, вопрос был чисто теоретическийа

Comment: Нет, не понял :) Чем select по паролю/логину отличается от других select, которых уж всяко больше делается?

Comment: @Deus: Не про вас, что вы, вы ведь спрашиваете, как правильно. Это про тех, кто _не_ спрашивает, и вводит ограничения.

---
А даже если придётся сохранять текст, определяемый юзером, через mysqli этот текст **никогда** не выполнится, хоть при вставке, хоть через select. Не бойтесь.

---
Удалил тот комментарий, чтобы никто не думал, что это на ваш счёт.

Comment: @klopp,я имел в виду WHERE. например, текстовая информация может содержать любые символы и находится в БД конечно в обработанном виде (escape_string и т.д.), однако  она не принимает участие в условии поиска,а просто выводится:

    SELECT text WHERE id='666'

А теоретически, как быть если пароль нужно сохранить в чистом виде, который **будет** участвовать в условии:

    SELECT text WHERE password='$password' 

Вот в чем вопрос. Комментарии давать уже не смогу, наверное...

Comment: @Deus: По идее, [так](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php):

    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT text WHERE password=?"))
    {
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $password);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($text);
        $stmt->fetch();
        $stmt->close();
    }

Comment: @VladD, и что - stmt надежно экранирует кавычки в приведенном вами коде? А если в $password будет что-то типа "' OR 1=1"?

Comment: @Deus: stmt вообще идёт через текстовое представление. Он сразу компилирует statement, и подставляет значение параметра.

Смотрите: какая проблема в SQL injection? Та, что в `SELECT text WHERE password=x AND 1 = 1` часть "`AND 1 = 1`" воспринимается не как часть параметра, а как отдельное условие. А при компиляции разбивка на параметры и условия заканчивается при `prepare`, больше никаких дополнительных условий возникнуть не может, значение `?` заменяется на значение параметра на уровне объектов.

Comment: @Deus, работа с placeholders (она же binding) никакого отношения к экранированию кавычек не имеет в принципе. При "экранировании" формируется обычная текстовая строка запроса. При работе через bind никаких вставок текста в исходное выражение не происходит. Можно считать, что эти самые символы `'?'` являются ссылками на внешние объекты, а сама строка с запросом никак не меняется.

Comment: Вот как-то так, попытался изобразить оба случая :) http://ato.su/resizer/i/9/2/50c0bf55.png

Comment: ответы к вопросу не имеют никакого отношения к вопросу. комментарии к вопросу каждый дополняет друг друга и должны быть ответами. парадокс. учитывая также имеющийся принятый ответ. и кто наставил всех этих плюсов да еще в таком количестве?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно кодировать все опасные символы на ***ASCII*** http://www.asciitable.com/
И использовать для этого специальные фильтры http://www.php.net/manual/ru/filter.filters.sanitize.php и флаги к ним.

…а на выходе декодировать

Answer (score 5):

храните в base64, скажем

Comment: Или crypt.

Comment: +1 за base64, но только в том случае если пароль нужно сохранить в первоначальном виде (иногда такое все же нужно).

Answer (score 0):

кто сказал, что пользователю разрешено вводить любые символы? точно также как и проверяете поля логина, емейла и еще чего-то там через регулярки, так и проверяйте пароль. Сбоку возле инпута пароля напишите что можно вводить и все. И да прибудут с вами печеньки.

Comment: @mountpoint, прикалываетесь? Я серьезно спросил. Я всегда кодирую пароль в md5 с какой-нибудь солью.

 Пароль может состоять из **любых** символов! На то от и пароль.

Comment: @Deus, я ничего не говорил о том, что не надо хешировать пароль! Просто нужно написать для пользователя, что в поле пароль можно вводить следующие символы A-я, A-z, *$%^& и т.д., и он поймет, что кавычки использовать низзя! Профит. Неужели так сложно понять?

Comment: @mountpoint, кавычки использовать **можно** и **нужно**, как и все остальные запрещенные символы!!!

Comment: @mountpoint, а с чего это вдруг нужно ограничивать пользователей в символах для пароля? Да пусть хоть табуляции и переводы строк вводит, имеет полное право, только надёжность выше будет.